# Skipping audio track using headphones

Tags: music, samsung-galaxy-ace, headphones

I have Samsung Galaxy Ace.

I listen to music using headphones. If I press button on headphones, it pauses/plays music. It is really annoying that I need to take phone out of my pocket, unlock the screen, and skip a song.

Is there a way to press a button on headphone, have it skip the current song and move to the next song like on Nokia phones? Is there any music player supporting this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried double press? While attempting try with different time gap between each press.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of solutions available on the Google Playstore -- just [search it for "headset control](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=headset+control&c=apps). Having a Philips headset, I use their [Philips Headset](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.philips.cl.headset) and am really satisfied with it: One tap = pause/play, two-tap = forward 1 track, 3 tap = backward 1 track. Long-Tap (hold it) = volume up, tap and then long-tap = volume down... Most of these apps follow that scheme, many also allow to customize it. [JAYS Headset Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.jays.headsetcontrol) should be a good option as well, but didn't work to well with my Philips headset; so if one doesn't do as expected, don't give up but try another.

Comment: The link to JAYS Headset Control appears dead.

Comment: @Firelord it's just an example; the search link should still work. [According to Appbrain](https://www.appbrain.com/app/se.jays.headsetcontrol) the app was indeed unpublished in 2017. I could also add the link to [my corresponding app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_headset) :)

Comment: I find plenty of apps that do more than needed and ask for more permissions than I am willing to give :(

Answer (score 2):

Double tapping on the button with two little dots works for me